# What is happening with vector array here?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, ant-colony

I'm solving the Traveling Salesman Problem via an ACO implementation in C++. However, I found out that the program I've built so far gives a segmentation fault.
(Note: I've limited the algorithm to only do one iteration of the colony for debugging purposes).

First off, I have a total of 52 cities taken from a file, and I distribute the ants so that every city has the same number of ants starting from it.

To store the distances between every pair of cities, I'm using a vector of vectors of doubles called Map (a square matrix). However, half-way during the execution it looks like these vectors are deleted. In this instance, it happens when calculating the path for the ant number 55. I've added a section of code just to highlight exactly where it crashes:

```
//DEBUGGING SECTION
                cout << "Size Roulette: " << Roulette.size() << endl;
                cout << "Size Remain: " << RemainingCities.size() << endl;
                cout << "Size Map: " << Map.size() << " x " << Map[0].size() << endl;

                int k = 0;
                cout << "Test: Map access: " << endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < Map.size(); ++i) //  HERE IT CRASHES AT ANT NUMBER 55
                    cout << Map[0][i] << " ";
                cout << endl;

                cout << "Test: Operation: " << Map[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]] << endl;

                Roulette[k] = pow((MAX_DIST - Map[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]]), heur_coef) + pow((pheromones[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]]), pher_coef);

//END OF DEBUGGING SECTION
```

There, the function Map[0].size() normally returns 52 (just like Map.size(), as it's supposed to be a square matrix), but at the crashing iteration it returns what looks like a memory address, and the moment I try to access any element, a segmentation fault occurs.

I have checked that the memory access is always correct, and I can access any other variable without issue except Map until that 55th ant.
I've tried different seeds for the roulette method, but it always crashes at the same place.

I have also varied the number of ants of the colony. If it's just one ant per city, the program executes without issue, but for any higher amount the program always crashes at the 55th ant.

You can download the full cpp file and the reading .tsp file from github:

https://github.com/yitosmash/ACO

In any case, I'll leave the full function here:

```
void ACO(const vector<City>& cities, const vector<vector<double>>& Map, int max_it, int num_ants, double decay, double heur_coef, double pher_coef, double pher_coef_elit)
{

        srand(30);

    //Initialise colony of ants (each ant is a vector of city indices)
    vector<vector<int>> Colony(num_ants, vector<int>(cities.size(), 0));

    //Initialise pheromone matrix
    vector<vector<double>> pheromones(cities.size(), vector<double>(cities.size(), 0));
    //Initialise costs vector(for etilist expansion)
    vector<double> costs(cities.size(), 0);

    //Auxiliar vector of indices
    vector<int> cityIndices(cities.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); ++i)
        cityIndices[i] = i;

    //Longest distance from Map, used for heuristic values.
    vector<double> longests(cities.size(), 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < cities.size(); ++i)
        longests[i] = *(max_element(Map[i].begin(), Map[i].end()));

    const double MAX_DIST = *(max_element(longests.begin(), longests.end()));
    longests.clear();


    int i=0;
    while(i<max_it)
    {
        for(int ant_i = 0; ant_i < num_ants; ++ant_i)
        {
            cout << "Ant: " << ant_i << endl;
            //City for ant_i to start at; each ant is assigned a determined starting city
            int starting_city = (int) ((float)ant_i/num_ants*cities.size());
            //cout << starting_city << endl;
            Colony[ant_i][0] = starting_city;

            //Get a vector with the cities left to visit
            vector<int> RemainingCities = cityIndices;

            //Remove starting city from remaining cities
            RemainingCities.erase(RemainingCities.begin() + starting_city);

            //Create path for ant_i
            for(int city_i = 1; city_i < Colony[ant_i].size(); ++city_i)
            {
                cout << "Calculating city number: " << city_i << endl;
                //Create roulette for next city selection
                vector<double> Roulette(RemainingCities.size(), 0);
                double total = 0;

                //DEBUGGING SECTION
                cout << "Size Roulette: " << Roulette.size() << endl;
                cout << "Size Remain: " << RemainingCities.size() << endl;
                cout << "Size Map: " << Map.size() << " x " << Map[0].size() << endl;

                int k = 0;
                cout << "Test: Map access: " << endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < Map.size(); ++i) //  HERE IT CRASHES AT ANT NUMBER 55
                    cout << Map[0][i] << " ";
                cout << endl;

                cout << "Test: Operation: " << Map[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]] << endl;

                Roulette[k] = pow((MAX_DIST - Map[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]]), heur_coef) + pow((pheromones[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[k]]), pher_coef);

                //END OF DEBUGGING SECTION

                for(int j = 0; j < RemainingCities.size(); ++j)
                {
                    //Heuristic value is MAX_DIST - current edge.
                    Roulette[j] = pow((MAX_DIST - Map[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[j]]), heur_coef) + pow((pheromones[Colony[ant_i][city_i-1]][RemainingCities[j]]), pher_coef);
                    total += Roulette[j];
                }
                cout << endl;
                //Transform roulette into stacked probabilities
                Roulette[0] = Roulette[0]/total;

                for(int j = 1; j < Roulette.size(); ++j)
                    Roulette[j] = Roulette[j-1] + Roulette[j] / total;

                //Select a city from Roulette
                int chosen = 0;
                double r = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX;
                while(Roulette[chosen] < r)
                    chosen++;

                //Add chosen city to
                Colony[ant_i][city_i] = RemainingCities[chosen];
                RemainingCities.erase(RemainingCities.begin() + chosen);
            }
            cout << endl;
            //Save cost of ant_i, for elitist expansion
            costs[ant_i] = pathCost(Colony[ant_i], Map);
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there anything significant about the number 55? Also have you tried using gdb?

Comment: `Map[0][i]` must probably be `Map[i]`, see my answer

Comment: If you use a range-based `for` loop on your STL containers, or `for_each()`, you’re less likely to run into these bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part is very suspicious :

```
for(int i = 0; i < Map.size(); ++i) //  HERE IT CRASHES AT ANT NUMBER 55
   cout << Map[0][i] << " ";
```

because *i* is the size of the *map* but you use it as an index in a probable string / vector, so you probably go out of the string/vector with an undefined behavior

probably you want

```
for(int i = 0; i < Map.size(); ++i)
   cout << Map[i] << " ";
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < Map[0].size(); ++i)
   cout << Map[0][i] << " ";
```

---

As I said in a remark at a moment `RemainingCities[0]` values -163172699 first in

> ```
>  cout << "Test: Operation: " << Map.at(Colony.at(ant_i).at(city_i-1)).at(RemainingCities.at(k)) << endl;
> ```

so is not a valid index in *Map*, but there is visible reason to have that looking at the code, so the reason is a probable write out of a *vector* destructing your memory elements.

To detect where I replaced all the `[...]` by `.at(...)` and the first error I have is in *ACO* at the line

> ```
>  costs.at(ant_i) = pathCost(Colony.at(ant_i), Map);
> ```

where `ant_i` values 52 while *costs* has 52 entries and *Colony* 260, so the error concerns *costs*

note that `ant_i` is set by the loop

> ```
>  for(int ant_i = 0; ant_i < num_ants; ++ant_i)
> ```

and in that case `num_ants` value 260 so much more than the size of *costs* which is defined as

> ```
>  vector<double> costs(cities.size(), 0);
> ```

but *cost* is just allocated and set but never read, so its goal is just to destruct the memory.

If I remove the two lines concerning it I do not have anymore an error and the program ends normally, there is no exception in a `.at(...)` and *valgrind* detect no error too.

Comment: As I said, Map is a square matrix (52x52), so that shouldn't matter. In fact, even if I try something like Map[3][2] it still gives an error.

Comment: @Thiro whatever, the loop as you did is wrong, in the best case you do not access to enough entries

Comment: ...except that in the 54 previous ants the loop DOES work perfectly fine (giving correct outputs) and the ant number has nothing to do with it. I know it's technically not correct but both Map() and Map[0]() sizes are the same so that doesn't matter in this context. I corrected it in any case, and the result is the same.

Comment: @Thiro yes, I got the full code and look at, I don't yet know why but your problem comes from when `RemainingCities[0]` values -163172699 so is not a valid index in Map. For sure you break your memory but I don't know where

Comment: @Thiro there are plenty of warning when I compile your code

Comment: I imagine I've made a mistake when accessing memory somewhere, but I just can't find any clues about where.

Comment: the most probable cause is you write in a vector outside of its limit

Comment: @Thiro I edited my answer, I found where you write out of a vector ... which is useless

Comment: Well, uh, here I of course don't use the costs vector, but this is still an unfinished version and I will need to access it in the future (specifically, to find which ants have the best solutions and to spread pheromones in their paths). In any case, you've found the problem (which is actually quite dumb, as always), so thanks!

Comment: @so you will have to reconsider the logic attached to _cost_ to correct it ;-)